# PRESS from the hat matrix and numerical stability from statsmodels ols.fit()

Tags: least-squares, residuals, leverage

Leave one out cross validation in the context of ordinary least squares regression can be done via the hat matrix:
The "hat" or projection matrix
$$
   H = X(X^T X)^{-1} X^T
$$
many fit statistics include a term which contains $(1-h_{ii})$. With the leverage of individual runs as:
$$
   h_{ii} = diag(H)_i
$$
For example the predicted error sum of residuals (PRESS, Montgomery and Vining p43). The PRESS residuals can be calculated as:
$$
   presiduals = \frac{residuals}{1 - h_{ii}}
$$
since the leverage of individual runs can become 1. The presiduals can become infinity for some runs. However, a leave one out cross validation would still give meaningful results in such a case. I did not find any literature on this topic which surprises me. Is this a common issue in OLS regression analysis?

Comment: I have never seen a leverage, hii, equal to 1. AFAICS, this can only happen in corner cases with degenerate data. Do you have a simple example that shows this?

Comment: Aside: statsmodels uses the generalized inverse, pinv, for both OLS parameter estimates and influence, diagonal of hat matrix. This provides a regularized solution for singular design matrix X. But I don't know if that can create a hii that goes to 1.

Comment: One practical case giving a $h_{ii}=1$ is a categorical variable represented with dummys where one level has only one observation. That gives a residual of zero, and the fit is exactly the same as if that observation left out!

Comment: I suspect you would only get that problem in situations where you probably ought to be using ridge-regression instead, which would be likely to solve that problem as well.

Comment: @Josef pinv might l give you values very close to 1 e.g. 0.9999998, the resulting statistic would not be inf but a rather unreliable measure.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, I will investigate the design further. I have not seen a leverage of one before either.